# Access Internet from One Router but Fall Back to another for Local Devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I am working on a robotics project in which we have a primary router that gives internet access, but it is configured to isolate devices connected to it. We have a secondary router that various robots are connected to; this router doesn't have internet access. I can use this second router for accessing the robots, but it is inconvenient to need to switch networks whenever I need to actually access the internet. Is there a way to configure my computer and/or the robots to be able to access the internet via the second router but still be accessible to each other over the second router's LAN?

Comment: I am not sure of the aim you seek. Why not link the second router to the first ? Then your PC and the robots will havecan access to Internet. 

Be sure to enable NAT on the second router and use in the robot / PC network a different subnet than each port of the first router. 

The router can also be setup (if it could) as a bridge (no address or NAT to setup)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.